# Passing a value from modified() to lookup() in ax

Tags: axapta, x++

How can I pass the value from `modified()` to `lookup()` method in **AX**?
I need the output as when I click the value in the textBox automatically sort the value in the lookup based on the value in the textbox.

Comment: need to pass the value to lookup() from modified()

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the **textbox property** `Autodeclaration = Yes`.

Then in the lookup method write this `NameOfTextBox.ValueStr();`

the result is the value of the textbox.

Comment: No need for auto declaration, just use `this.text()` in the lookup method.